# onclick drop Up Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to make a menu that drops up. is there anyway to do this without the need massive feature scripts? The click events are for closing the menu if body is clicked, and closing the menu if the link is clicked, seems to be buggy :(

Can be Jquery of javascript

html:

```
<div class="cc-btn">            
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="tablabel country-btn" id="portimg"></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a id="mclose" href="#home">Overview</a>
    <a id="mclose" href="#about">Application Process</a>
    <a id="mclose" href="#contact">Investment Options</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 99999;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
        -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out .3s;
    transition: ease-out .3s;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: rgba(220,220,220,0.3)}

.show {display:block; top:-10.5em;left:0em}
```

jquery

```
$(".country-btn").click(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").slidedown({
  direction: "up" }, 100);
});

$(html).click(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").hide();
});

/* Clicks within the dropdown won't make
   it past the dropdown itself */
$("#myDropdown").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#mclose").click(function(){
  $("#myDropdown").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS animation is all you need :

CSS :

```
.dropdown{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100; // big value if needed
  top: 100vh; // hide dropdown 
  left: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out; // or whatever else
}
.dropdown.active{
  transform: translate(0, -100%); // dropdown come up
}
```

JS:

```
$('.country-btn').click(()=>{
  $(".dropdown").toggleClass('active'); // dropdown switch state each time you click
});

$('#container').click(()=>{ // dropdown off when content clicked, see bellow note
  $('dropdown').removeClass('active');
});
```

Note : To implement the body click that close dropdown, just wrap your content in a div (here #container) then link the unactivate dropdown event. 
It prevents your country-button/dropdown clicks to call dropdown off event.

Feel free to ask any question if you dont get it well !

Comment: Ok i have spent sometime playing with it. Not sure what im doing wrong here still. I put it in a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/1/

Comment: Ok my bad, its just because `bottom` in dropdown.active doesnt override the top value. See the edited .active css :)

Comment: Thanks for that, you got me on the right track. having trouble with closing the menu when clicking outside the menu. And also it twitches up on mouse leave. here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/81/

Comment: Your html is messed up, you should never use an id more than once. Wait my own attempt via fiddle (:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1exnczoo/7/ its important to have separate elements to handle the events correctly, your container should also be set to fill the page, so wherever the user click outside of your menu, he clicks on the container